# deny submitting form if the username exist on the mysql db

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i just pluged a `JQuery username check` which worked fine , the problem is that my form still submitting even the username exist on my `Mysq Database`, how can i configure it to deny submitting to my `server side .php file` if it exists ?

here is my Jquery plugin javascript code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {


        //the min chars for checkusername
        var min_chars = 3;

        //result texts
        var characters_error = 'Minimum amount of chars is 3';
        var checking_html = '<img src="images/checkusername.gif" /> Checking...';

        //when button is clicked
        $('#check_checkusername_availability').click(function(){
            //run the character number check
            if($('#checkusername').val().length < min_chars){
                //if it's bellow the minimum show characters_error text
                $('#checkusername_availability_result').html(characters_error);
            }else{          
                //else show the cheking_text and run the function to check
                $('#checkusername_availability_result').html(checking_html);
                check_availability();
            }
        });


  });

//function to check checkusername availability  
function check_availability(){

        //get the checkusername
        var checkusername = $('#checkusername').val();

        //use ajax to run the check
        $.post("frontend/functions/f_checkuser.php", { checkusername: checkusername },
            function(result){       
                //if the result is 1
                if(result == 1){
                    //show that the checkusername is available
                    $('#checkusername_availability_result').html('<span class="is_available"><b>' +checkusername + '</b> is Available</span>');
                }else{
                    //show that the checkusername is NOT available
                    $('#checkusername_availability_result').html('<span class="is_not_available"><b>' +checkusername + '</b> is not Available</span>');
                }
        });

}
```

here is my html field

```
 <table border="0" >
          <tr>
            <td valign="middle"><input class="input_field_12em required userUserName" name="userUserName" id="checkusername"></td>
            <td valign="middle"><input type='button' id='check_checkusername_availability' value='Check Availability'></td>
            <td><div id='checkusername_availability_result'></div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: what form? i see no form. well you could disable it with the js.

Comment: sorry , just added the html form to the question

Comment: What does "frontend/functions/f_checkuser.php" return?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli it returns 0 or 1 , 0 means the username is not available , 1 means its available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for the callback to fire for your AJAX request, then you can either submit the form or not:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (event, extra) {
        if (typeof extra == 'undefined') {
            extra = false;
        }
        //if no extra argument is passed via `.trigger()` then don't submit the form
        return extra;
    });
    $('#check_checkusername_availability').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'frontend/functions/f_checkuser.php',
            type : 'post',
            data : { checkusername : $('#checkusername').val() },
            success : function (serverResponse) {
                //now check the serverResponse variable to see if the name exists, if not then run this code:
                $('form').trigger('submit', true);
            },
            error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /*don't forget to handle possible errors*/ }
        });
    });
});
```

Otherwise, you can force the AJAX request to be synchronous by setting `async:false`, but this will lock-up the browser until the AJAX request resolves, which could be seconds where the user can't do anything. This gives the impression that your script is broken to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your html but it seems like clicking on object with id `check_checkusername_availability` triggers form submit in some way. Is it a submit button? If that's the case just change it to the regular button. And add callback to handle the resonse.